# AS3 AIR - Client close connection

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am making a server and client in air with as3 (ServerSocket - TCP), and I want the client to be able to disconnect from server, like client.disconnect(); or something. I also want the server to be able to kick client. Is that possible in as3 with air?

Comment: Since you provide no code or detail, I can only suggest you use a big boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can use socket.close() to disconnect clients from server.